# Who are these characters on this unofficial New Hope poster?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, a-new-hope, poster-design

This 1990 [Russian(?) version](http://io9.gizmodo.com/incredibly-weird-star-wars-posters-you-probably-havent-1521987518) of the poster for Star Wars: A New Hope is *somewhat different* from Western versions.

Assuming Darth Vader is the one in the middle, who are the characters along the left and right hand side of the frame?

[image]

Comment: There isn't enough caffeine in the world to help me make sense of this.

Comment: The article you linked to says it's Russian.

Comment: The one in the middle left could be a Dianoga; http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_rzdB5a4kLAo/SqrVJxw9m7I/AAAAAAAAQLg/hNzY3U7nsCg/s320/dianoga02.jpg

Comment: see my answer to your previous question :P... I'm sticking to my guns on this one, lol.

Comment: How is Darth Vader the one in the middle?

Comment: @SQB - A number of features tally; the stripes on the chest-plate, the coloured panel on the chest-plate, the central crest on the helmet, the grey cape elements on the tops of the shoulders; http://www.versusbattle.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/darth-vader.jpg?w=240

Comment: upvoted solely for the italicized "somewhat different" in the question :D

Comment: Honestly that looks more like Darth Pumaman.

Comment: Based on the number of lightsabers, I'd say it's Grievous.

Comment: Um...... the idea that any of these are characters from the movie is bizarre and possible a bit insulting, but, on the left..... are some of those Han, Kenobi, Luke and Chewie? And on the right..... the Canteena band? We all know they were the true villains of the original trilogy. Frankly, the very idea that one of these could be Leia is ridiculous.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - I think Leia might be the one on the top-right with the headphones on

Comment: Oh, cause the buns..... that makes sense. I did wonder if the top two on the right were supposed to be 3PO and R2, but I think you're right.

Comment: @Radhil So the darkside changed this guy into that? http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ZOkwhA-yazM/UweytEIM9bI/AAAAAAAABdc/7MziAEF2WTw/s1600/The+Pumaman.jpg

Comment: @suchiuomizu - that's my theory and I'm sticking to it.

Comment: The third one on the right reminds me of Greedo. Hey, we might crack this after all!

Comment: Dunno about the characters on the sides but the characters at the bottom are Cyrillic. According to the little I remember from the Russian class I took, the title is Star Wars (not "A New Hope") and it's a cosmic western produced in the USA.

Comment: @user14111 - It literally says "*Space Western - Manufactured USA*" along the bottom as well as "*Cast: M. Hamill, X(?). Ford, A. Guinness and K. Fisher & etc"* on the right and *"written by George Lucas"* on the left.

Comment: @Radhil  I don't think caffeine would be adequate for this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some of my answers are, by my own admission, unfettered guesswork. This poster, like the other Star Wars posters from Russia which have come up recently, is probably too spaced out (no pun intended) and impressionistic to make much sense of. I don't recall seeing an animate cactus or a bunson burner in any of the films, for instance. It definitely isn't good enough to [go on the fridge.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bm9QUuNVjXE&feature=youtu.be&t=2m12s)

This answer is a starting point. Others can feel free to edit in further suggestions - or to post their own answers.

The article that's linked to in the question doesn't actually say that it's a poster for *A New Hope*. My Russian isn't good enough to translate the title but, unless someone else can verify, I'm going to assume that it could be a poster for any of the original trilogy films. So I'm going to put forward character suggestions from ESB and ROTJ as well.

**From top to bottom and left to right:**

**1.** [image: 1]
**No idea.**

**2.** [image: 2]
 **No idea.**

**3.** [image: 3] [image: 4]
 **Obi-Wan Kenobi?**
 The drawing has a beard, at any rate. This is the one I'm most sure about.

**4.** [image: 5] [image: 6]
**Dianoga?**
Suggestion by Valorum.

**5.** [image: 7] [image: 8] [image: 9]
**Greddo? Or maybe Yoda?**
Someone green, anyway.

**6.** [image: 10] [image: 11] [image: 12]
**Luke/Han?**
The goggles remind me of the ski-wear that both Luke and Han wore on Hoth.

**7.** [image: 13] [image: 14]
**C3-PO?**
A very angry C3-PO, at that if I'm right.

**8.** [image: 15] [image: 16]
**Leia?**
I agree with Valorum. I think that's Leia.

**9.** [image: 17] [image: y][image: 18]
**Arleil Schous? Or Chewie?**
Ench suggests that it may be Schous, which is probably a better fit than Chewbacca. On the one hand, Chewie isn't a T-shirt-wearing Aardvark. On the other hand, the artist was blatantly stoned when they drew this.

**10.** [image: 19] [image: u]
**Momaw Nadon?**
Ench suggests him for this figure. I'm not convinced but then again I have no better ideas.

**11.** [image: 20]
**No idea.**
I this wasn't drawn in 1990 then I'd have said BB-8. Sadly, we must rule him out.

**12.** [image: 21] [image: 22]
**R2-D2?**
If you ignore the triangle it could be him.

**13.** [image: 23] [image: 24]
**Vader?**
I agree with the consensus. This must be Darth.

Comment: 9 looks more like greddo

Comment: 9 could be Arleil Schous - The Wolfman in the cantina.
10 could be Momaw Nadon - http://cantinacustoms.tripod.com/0b2cfe10.jpg
12 could be this guy - The triangle is upside down, but that would hardly be the weirdest thing on this poster. http://img.lum.dolimg.com/v1/images/creature-cantina_3fdabe24.jpeg?region=289%2C151%2C1595%2C799&width=768

Comment: The big white letters say "Star Wars" (so, the original movie) and the small white letters underneath say "cosmic western" and "produced(?) — USA". (I don't know Russian but I took a couple classes in Russian in some bygone millennium.)

Comment: The actors are M. Hemill, H. Ford, A. Ginnes, K. Fisher, et al.

Comment: This is a poster for A New Hope.  Yoda didn't exist yet and the goggles by which you identify #6 have not yet been worn.

Comment: @CHEESE Do you know for sure that it's for A New Hope? I don't speak Russian myself.

Comment: Or it could be " hey poster guy, draw a poster with a bunch of aliens and a guy made of metal, they fight with energy swords of different colors" or then again, movie posters could be highly interpretive in that area, which would be kind of cool in it's way. I just feel like the person who made this may have heard of the characters but never actually saw them. Or maybe never heard of them either is possible too. It's just so out there. I think the message is clear: this movie is going to be interesting. Although 4 could be a Star Destroyer with an evil all seeing imperial eye.

Comment: Did you read the question?

Comment: @CHEESE - The poster was made after all three films had been released.

Comment: Has Jabba been rejected as a possibility for º12?  The sloping sides suggest increasing girth, so it could be conceivable.

Comment: In the absence of a *confirmed* answer (from the artist, for example) I'm going to accept this. I think it's as good as its gonna get.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure that the second of the top left is r2-d2 because of the domed top and flat sides

Comment: The above answer is a “community wiki”, so you should edit it with your answer rather than post a new one.  When doing so, be certain to provide a picture beside in the same manner as has been done for the others — i would suggest moving the R2-D2 picture already there.  You are describing **º1** in that list.