# Who is this lizard-man on the Return of the Jedi poster?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, return-of-the-jedi, poster-design

This poster by [Tibor Helényi](http://dangerousminds.net/comments/crazy_hungarian_posters_for_the_original_star_wars_trilogy) (made to advertise the opening of *Return of the Jedi* in Hungary in 1984) is pretty respectful of the original and drawn by someone who appears to have seen the film, or at least other posters advertising the film.

**Who is the lizard guy in the bottom left corner?**

[image: Hungarian poster for Return of the Jedi]  [image: detail of same]

For the record I'm aware that [Martin Schneider of DangerousMinds.com](http://dangerousminds.net/comments/crazy_hungarian_posters_for_the_original_star_wars_trilogy) notes that the artist has a tendency to add "*big scary lizard creatures who find no correlative in the movies*". I could only find one other example (in his [earlier poster for *A New Hope*](http://dangerousminds.net/content/uploads/images/made/content/uploads/images/HungaryStarWars_465_465_649_int.jpg)) which doesn't seem to represent much of a *tendency*.

Comment: possibly an interpretation of the Gamorran guards? http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gamorrean

Comment: @NKCampbell - Good thinking, that man - https://www.bigbadtoystore.com/images/products/out/large/ATT10012.jpg

Comment: I'm no master of Hungarian language but that title has to be Return of the Jedi, doesn't it?

Comment: Plus, that's definitely the second Death Star in Vader's eye.

Comment: @TheIronCheek - [Are you my conscience](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Wzkb_3d9NA&feature=youtu.be&t=1m13s)?

Comment: it's certainly for Jedi: Lambda shuttle, speeder bike, Death Star II

Comment: @Valorum - :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=am3UFc23kJk

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152540/who-is-this-character-on-the-star-wars-a-new-hope-poster

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152541/who-are-these-characters-on-the-new-hope-poster?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: That is the ugly face of capitalism.

Comment: Are you sure the poster wasn't drawn by Peter Jackson?

Comment: @iMerchant - If it had been drawn by Jackson, there would be [four separate commentaries](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings:_The_Fellowship_of_the_Ring_(extended_edition)), one from Jackson, one from the Producer, one from the inker and one from the guy who made the paints along with eight "making of" documentaries.

Comment: Perhaps it is Cthulhu? It certainly looks like him.

Comment: You know what I'd like to see in one of the Star Wars films (canon or EU)?  A free-range Rancor.  Like... some of the team are zipping past this field or something, and out in the field are some Rancors having a frolic.

Comment: @Valorum Special edition, Disc 1 of 12, box 2 of 5.  With 32 hours of new material.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Echoing NKCampbell's comment, this could be Gamorrean Guard [Thok](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Thok). Certainly the tusks are dramatically elongated, and he's more lizard than pig, but you can certainly see the resemblance in the horns, pig nose, tusks, squinting eyes, green skin and the fact that he's holding a pike.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

**It's a [Rancor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rancor/Legends).**

Imagine if someone described a Rancor to you, based on [Ralph McQuarrie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_McQuarrie)'s early sketch design. Imagine that description went through some dubious language translation.

Wouldn't it look something like that?

For reference, here's a copy of that sketch.  To me, it's easy to get from this sketch to that image if all you had was a written description that had been translated from English.

[image]

Also this early concept art by [Joe Johnston](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Joe_Johnston) shows the tusks:

[image]

Comment: Why is it holding  some sort of staff and has horns.... This is a good answer, I'm just not convinced.

Comment: @Skooba - Well, when you're a fashionable Rancor....  Honestly I don't know. As I said, it'll be an artist's interpretation and s/he would have drawn something that made sense for that time and that artist.